# How to solve the following relationship?

Tags: regular-expressions

We can easily seen that
$${q^{2n}} = {q^n}\left( {{q^n} - 1} \right) + {q^n},{q^{3n}} = {q^n}{\left( {{q^n} - 1} \right)^2} + 2{q^n}\left( {{q^n} - 1} \right) + {q^n}.$$
Similarly, we assume that
$${q^{mn}} = {q^n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{m - 1} {{a_k}{{\left( {{q^n} - 1} \right)}^k}}  + {q^n}.$$
then, how to obtain the coefficient $a_k$.

Comment: How about taking $q^{mn}$ as $q^n((q^n-1)+1)^{m-1}$, then use binomial theorem?

Comment: That's the answer....Why not post it as an answer?